# ReactJS. I try to make dynamic input field together using react-calendar package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-calendar

I want to build a dynamic form using react-calendar and input field input (type: time). Whenever a user wants to insert their times in a specific date, the input field will be reset to the first index and will need to enter their times.

I have managed to make the input field dynamic but I cannot get all the arrays with the same ISO DateTime value.

Here is the link to my sandbox for the case
https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-rgb-m8g9j?file=/src/App.js